# How do I tell MS Excel to use the non-standard decimal separator in graphs and charts?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, language, input-languages

MS Excel 2010, using US English as default language.  I have a document that needs to use the interpunct (·) as the decimal separator.  I can go to File -> Options -> Advanced -> Decimal separator and set it to the interpunct (either via the alt code, 0183 or using charmap).  This works great for the cell contents, but it doesn't appear to affect the charts.  How do I get the charts to reflect the correct decimal separator?

Comment: Charts *should* use the number format of the data series. Try using a custom format on the data series rather than changing the spreadsheet options.

Comment: I don't think that custom formatting can change decimal separators.

Comment: @Raystafarian So, it appears this may be a bug in Office 2010.  In Office 2013, all I have to do is go to File -> Options -> Advanced -> Decimal Separator and change it to use the interpunct, and all is well.  No combination of cell formating, axis formatting, or other tricks would work for the chart in Office 2010 (in this particular case, it was a data-table being used as the axis).