# Adjust decimal separator in imported charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, charts, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-word-2013

I am about to write an English document with the German versions of MS Word and Excel. I use Excel to create a chart which I import into the Word document (by Copy & Paste).

I can tell Excel to use a custom decimal separator (`.` instead of `,`) via File, Options, Advanced. However, these settings are overruled when I paste the chart into Word and the chart again uses `,` as the decimal separator (for axis labels).

Is there a way I can configure the decimal separator for the imported chart in Word?

Comment: Despite the Excel option, there are system wide settings under your regional settings tab. Change them too

Comment: You mean the default editing language? I tried that, too. Doesn't change the chart (after re-pasting).

Comment: Try to "update" the chart to make it reflect system/Excel settings. e.g. if you have numbers in the chart axis labels - check into the settings for these (right click on the axis for a menu named 'Format axis' - where you also find a 'Numbers' tab.)

Comment: @Hannu: Already checked this tab. But the numbers tab doesn't allow to set decimal separators.

Comment: Is it greyed out? Can you see a tick for `use system settings` or similar?  (I do not have Excel at hand)

Comment: Note that the mere fact that you go into the tab and change something may initiate a fresh 'readout' from the system wide settings.

Comment: @Hannu There is just no option to change regional settings in the numbers tab (nor a "use system settings"). And I'd prefer not to change the windows global settings just to get another separator.

Comment: It might also be dependent on software versions - please see http://superuser.com/q/693613/346288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three places to look:

1) System settings (Windows: Control panel, regional settings, Ubuntu: System Settings, Language support -> Regional formats
which should reflect/be reflected by `$ locale`)

2) Excel / Spreadsheet settings: Excel, File, Options, Advanced  (LibreOffice?)

3) Cell/Item/Object local settings: e.g. Right click 'Chart axis' select 'Format axis' and go to the 'Numbers' tab. or press `CTRL`+`1` with a cell selected.

Comment: Changing the system settings works. But I really would like a method which doesn't change the whole system.

Comment: Ahh... I missed the fact that **you're pasting an Excel chart into Word**. How about "3)" above - but for WORD or Excel via launch from FROM the embedded object in Word?

Comment: No, doesn't do it either.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICS in Office 2013, the default paste format is "Microsoft Office Graphic Object".

If you are just pasting (not linking/embedding) then you could change the separators in Excel (as you are doing), use Paste->Special to specify one of the graphic formats, then change the separators back.

If you are using Paste->Link or embed, once you have the result you need with the separators you want, you should be able to prevent Word from updating the field *result* by selecting the field code and using ctrl-F11 to lock it. With an embed, you can get to the menu to change the separators using a copy of Excel opened "outside Word"

Either way, when you need to change the graphic again I think you will need to unlock the field (ctrl-shift-F11, change the separators to the ones you want, update the graphic, lock the field again, then change the separators back.