# Wrong decimal separator when inputting axis range in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, locale, microsoft-excel-2016

I have my decimal symbol set to a **decimal point** in Windows Regional Settings. This particular computer is running Windows 10, but I am experiencing this issue on Windows 7, 8, and 8.1 too.

In regular Excel cells (and in other "numeric" programs like the Windows calculator), this means that when I hit the comma button on the numpad, a point is inserted.

However, when editing the axis bounds (e.g. `Format Axis -> Bounds -> Minimum`) of a chart, the comma button on the numpad inserts a comma.

I looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/802283/adjust-decimal-separator-in-imported-charts#) but none of the answers helped.

According to colleagues, this happens in both Excel 2013 and 2016. This may happen in Excel 2010 but I don't have access to that version anymore.

Comment: So you hit `.` on the numpad but get a `,`? Does this happen in Notepad?

Comment: My numpad has a `,` button, not a `.` button. I'm not using the locale of my country. In notepad, and other places that expect text, it inserts a literal `,`, while in Excel cells it inserts `.` (except for when I try to format axis, as described above).